# questions about logistic regression

Tags: classification, logistic-regression, binary, linearly-separable

In the following Linear Regression discussion I didn't understand a few things:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So my questions are:

1. In the third slide:
   What does this probability means $P\left(y_i|x_i\right)$ and accordingly what does it mean to maximize it ?
   Does it mean to maximize both $P\left(y_i=1|x_i\right)$ and $P\left(y_i=0|x_i\right)$, and as higher this probability, the more stable and rightful results we get, and accordingly the more correct weights $w^*$ we get ?
2. In the fourth slide I don't see the math, could anyone detail it ? How did we get that result ?

Comment: its just like replcae the p(y=1/x) and p(y=0/x) with the values given in the second slide and do the logarithmic operations. You will directly land on the desired result

Comment: If you want me put, I will do that but takes time to type everything. And coming to the first question, No not exaclty, it doesn't mean to maximize both, according to the value of ```yi```,  one part of the ```L``` will be vanished, like if ```yi``` is 1 then ```L``` will be left with the first part only and viceversa.

Comment: Just go through the cost function section in this link https://towardsdatascience.com/optimization-loss-function-under-the-hood-part-ii-d20a239cde11 , you will clearly understand the thing.

Comment: I'll look at it later, and if I'll need more clarifications, I'll write them here according to your answer. I guess the math should be fine.

Comment: I see what they did there, in that link. The explanation is a little bit lacking. They just telling you "Look, that logistic function punishes a lot and e.t.c ...", so it's a little bit amateur, you don't exactly see where from they took the minus logarithm as in the third slide, that I brought here. I think the explanation for the maximizing that P is that you want to maximize the prediction where x given on any y answer, it could be 1 and it could be 0, equally it could be written as $y_i*P(y_i=1|x_i)+(1-y_i)P(y_i=0|x)$.

Comment: then I think it makes sense. So it's not maximaizng both, it is maximizing the relevant of them with respect to $y_i$, what do you think ?

Comment: Exactly, spot on. That's how the loss function is. Based on the value of ```yi```, it maximizes the respective part